# take a screenshot in the local unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, continuous-integration

how to make a screenshot (preview) without using an emulator (or device)?

I need any quick mechanism in order to take a bunch of screenshots (png) for different screen sizes/layouts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure any of the layout stuff will work in just a JVM. So would need a headless emulator, emulator or Device to have a screen to screenshot. Robo Electric might allow to to run the code without emulator or Device.

Then you can get layout to draw in to a Bitmap backed Canvas and then save the bitmap to file, this does require you to run the code,

Note this will save the whole layout including any off screen elements.
e.g. A scollview will normal be made to fit the screen, so it will only show what is on screen at the time (same goes for things like recyclerview)
But for things like TableLayouts inside of a scrollview you will get the whole TableLayout including off screen elements

Code:

```java
        tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table);

        Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
        // Double the bitmap size and scale the Canvas to get a better resolution picture
        // (Basically doubling the virtual screen resolution (Optional)
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tableLayout.getWidth()*2, tableLayout.getHeight()*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
        bitmapCanvas.scale(2.0f, 2.0f);
        tableLayout.draw(bitmapCanvas);

        // uri is from SAF in this instance but any fileOutputStream can be used
        try{
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd =
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
                            openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(
                            pfd.getFileDescriptor());


            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored

            fileOutputStream.close();
            pfd.checkError();
            pfd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("N", e.toString());
        }
```

**Update:**
If they view has not been laid out on a screen, then you can do it manually instead of `findViewById`
e.g.

```java
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();

tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TabLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TabLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            tableLayout.layout(0, 0, tableLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), tableLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
```

But I still think that without something like Robo Electric providing all the "Android" classes to a standard JVM even this won't work.

Comment: 1) How do I set the URI to save the file to the PC (unit local test)?  2) I tried a similar solution -> the debugger shows an empty image (the size is correct)

Comment: 1)The uri was picked using the GUI in my case, but in your case you can programatically create a `File` object and get a fileOutputStream from that instead. 2) As I said with all the Frameworks available then it is likely to draw nothing.